# How does a microwave steamer work?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, microwaves, food

While I am no physicist, I am convinced this is a physics question:

*How does a [microwave steamer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22microwave+steamer%22&tbm=isch) work?*

It seems like a scam to me. Wouldn't the microwave be cooking the food and heating the water at the same time? So why can't I just put the food in the microwave without the water at the bottom (ie without a steamer at all)? In fact, all the recipes in the instructions manual are possible using a microwave alone without the steamer (according to a quick google search I did).

Comment: Having extra water in order to create steam in the microwave is better than sucking all that water out of the food itself.

Answer (score 3):

@Jon Custer comment is correct.

One of the reasons for cooking bagged frozen vegetable in the bag in a microwave oven is that the steam cannot escape. This cooks the vegetables faster and avoids drying them out.

Unfortunately, not all foods that you would like to steam come in a microwavable bag. Thus the possible purpose of a microwave steamer. Though I personally have no experience with them and therefore cannot attest to how well they work.

Hope this helps.